# How to fill table with JSON data in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, json, swift, tableview, alamofire

I created a tableView in which I want to put news using this link

```
   https://api.sis.kemoke.net/news
```

There are three things which I want to get and populate the table.

```
    String title
    String text
    String link
```

Here is my class

```
    import Alamofire //Framework for handling http requests
    import UIKit
```

/*A class which will process http requests, receive the news as string and fill the array with such data which will be displayed in a table*/
class NewsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
//Array which holds the news
var newsData:Array< String > = Array < String >()

// Download the news
func downloadData() {
    Alamofire.request("https://api.sis.kemoke.net/news").responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request)  // original URL request
        print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
        print(response.data)     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

        //Optional binding to handle exceptions
        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    downloadData()
    extractData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source
// Number of sections i table vie
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return newsData.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = newsData[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

// Extract the data from the JSON
func extractData() {
    Alamofire.request("https://api.sis.kemoke.net/news").responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)

        if let json = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(json)")
            self.newsData = json as! Array
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Navigation

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
```

}

Later-on I will try to get the image as well but for now those three variables should be enough.

Comment: Why do you have two methods (`extractData` and `downloadData`) that both do the same thing? Why are both called from `viewDidLoad`? Why doesn't either one reload the table?

Comment: @rmaddy I thought that it is necesary to call them from  viewDidLoad. It is due to the my inexperience as I am new to mobile app development. Please would you explain how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all create a custom struct for the data

  ```
  struct News {
    let title : String
    let text : String
    let link : String

    init(dictionary: [String:String]) {
       self.title = dictionary["title"] ?? ""
       self.text = dictionary["text"] ?? ""
       self.link = dictionary["link"] ?? ""
    }
  }
  ```
- The data source array is

  ```
  var newsData = [News]()
  ```
- Use **only** `downloadData()`, delete the other method.
  Using a custom struct the parsing is quite simple:

  ```
  func downloadData() {
      Alamofire.request("https://api.sis.kemoke.net/news").responseJSON { response in
          print(response.request)  // original URL request
          print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
          print(response.data)     // server data
          print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

          //Optional binding to handle exceptions
          if let json = response.result.value as? [[String:String]] {
              self.newsData = json.map{ News(dictionary: $0) }
              self.tableView.reloadData()
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- In `cellForRow...` display the title

  ```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
      let news = newsData[indexPath.row]
      cell.textLabel?.text = news.title
      return cell
  }
  ```